# Using Firebase data and create Google Maps API markers on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make an iOS app, working with Google Maps API and Firebase. It should show many markers on the map.

The maps part works well. However, I want to retrieve location data (latitude, longitude) from Firebase Real-time database, then put into *marker.position*. (then it should create a marker, right?)

It struck many days, I still can't show a marker (but I can print correct data from Firebase database).

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("locations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let location = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                for eachLocation in location {
                    print("Location: \(eachLocation)")

                    if let locationCoordinate = eachLocation.value as? [String: Any] {
                        if let lavLatitude = locationCoordinate["latitude"] as? Double {
                            if let lavLongitude = locationCoordinate["longitude"] as? Double {

                                print(lavLatitude)
                                print(lavLongitude)

                                let marker = GMSMarker()
                                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lavLatitude, lavLongitude)
                                marker.map = mapView
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My code reference from Github: [appsmall/Map-Demo](https://github.com/appsmall/Map-Demo).

It really weird, when I copy and replace my **GoogleService-Info.plist**. My app can show markers from his Firebase database!

I am wondering anything wrong in my database: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKntU.png).

Of course, I searched and tried many different solutions here, but still not work, if you need more information, please tell me, thanks!

Comment: Does your marker have an `iconView` (`marker.iconView = someView`)?

Comment: No marker.iconView, just regular Google Maps marker

Comment: Try replacing your marker positioning with this `marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lavLatitude, longitude: lavLongitude)`

Comment: No, I tried it.

Comment: I think the problem is from firebase database....

Comment: But the `lat` and `lon` print as expected, right?

Comment: Yes, I can print lavLatitude and lavLongitude as expected.

Comment: Then it can't be your database because you have the doubles right there. And if you swap out the plist file and do nothing else, then it works?

Comment: Exactly, if I swap out the plist file, and do nothing else, it works!

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using Firestore, btw?

Comment: I don't have any reason, also, this is my first time using firebase and database.

Comment: Then if I were you, I'd start a new project and take each API one at a time. You made a mistake somewhere along the way and only you'll be able to find it. Just start over and really learn this technology. First, get your map up and running. Learn the best practices for how to use location manager. Add markers to the map using hard-coded numbers. Then, and only then, install Firestore and learn that. If you have no reason to use RTDB, don't use it. Take your time, read the documentation. You can master this stuff in a few days. You'll be a much better programmer for it.

Comment: And for what you're doing, loading a Google Map and populating it with markers from Firebase, don't use any tutorials. All of this stuff is in Google's dox. Just my .02

Comment: I see, thanks for your suggestion and help. I will do it step by step.

Comment: I think the important thing here is to learn one API at a time

Comment: Any solution to this?? I got same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using Annotation instead of GMSMarker():

**Replace this**

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lavLatitude, lavLongitude)
marker.map = mapView
```

**With this**

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lavLatitude, longitude: lavLongitude)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: Annotation() ? 
It shows red warning sign: Use of unresolved identifier 'Annotation'

Comment: I am sorry, it still warning in "mapView.addAnnotation(placeAnnotation)" => "Value of type GMSMapView has no member 'addAnnotation'; did you mean 'addInteraction'?"

Comment: @Stijnk008 he's not using `MapKit`, he's using `GoogleMaps`.